# How to solve this 2-D deconvolution $g*f=δ$?

Tags: convolution, image-processing

$g*f=δ$, where $*$ refers to convolution, $δ$ is impulse, $f$ and $g$ is 2-D matrix, $f$ is given and sum of all the elements in $f$ equals $0$, $g$ is unknown. i want to find $g$.

i would appreciate it if you also can provide with matlab code

thanks in advance. this problem has bothered me for long.

Comment: I'd have guessed $\delta$ is the _impulse_, rather than the impulse _response_.  Could that be what you meant?

Comment: yes, sorry for my mistake. I am new in image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is really convolution, on the transform side you get $\hat f \hat g = 1 $, however, when you represent convolution as a matrix the entries in every row are the same numbers rotated, so the fact that the sum of all the elts of f is $0$ means the sum over a row is $0$ which means $\hat f(0) = 0$ and this equation will not have any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has [several image deconvolution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/deconvblind.html) (deblurring) commands; see the link for example code.

The next time you should post your image processing questions at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks. very helpful info..